# VBA - Object rejected

Tags: vba, object, copy, copy-paste, paste

I am a new learner of VBA programming. It is really so tough to figure out the error. For the following code, there is always a message of

> 'object rejected'

May I understand why it is happening ToT

Thank you so much!!!

```
Sub SelectAndCopyCellsWithValue()

    Dim SingleCell As Range

    Dim area As Range
    Set area = ActiveSheet.Range("C158", "ED158")

    For Each SingleCell In area
        If SingleCell <> 0 Then
            SingleCell.Select
            SingleCell.Value.Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
            SingleCell.Offset(-155, 0).Value.Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
            SingleCell.Offset(-154, 0).Value.Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)

        End If
    Next SingleCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Which specific line is raising this error? I've never seen an error message that says "object rejected". Are you sure that wasn't "Object required"?

Comment: Also `SingleCell.Select` is redundant, remove it

Answer (score 1):

```
SingleCell.Value.Copy
```

`Range.Value` is a *value*, not an object: values don't have members that can be invoked - this instruction is illegal and raises an **object required** error, because, well, an object would be required in order for that `.Copy` member call to be made.

You want to invoke `Range.Copy`, so do `SingleCell.Copy`.

If you mean to just copy the value and not the formatting, borders, conditional formats and whatnot, then don't involve the clipboard and just write to the cells:

```
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

targetSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = SingleCell.Value
targetSheet.Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = SingleCell.Offset(-155, 0).Value
targetSheet.Range("A3").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = SingleCell.Offset(-154, 0).Value
```